# rails default actions are missing params in routing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Excuse me for my lame question, but i`m stuck.
Plain and simple in my routes.rb file i have:

```
resource :books do
    resource :reviews
  end
```

running rake routes | grep reviews gives me:

```
books_reviews POST   /books/reviews(.:format)      reviews#create
 new_books_reviews GET    /books/reviews/new(.:format)  reviews#new
edit_books_reviews GET    /books/reviews/edit(.:format) reviews#edit
                   GET    /books/reviews(.:format)      reviews#show
                   PUT    /books/reviews(.:format)      reviews#update
                   DELETE /books/reviews(.:format)      reviews#destroy
```

My question is: where is the :id param in the show and edit actions? According to this tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html there should be "id" params in the routing, like this:

```
new_books_reviews GET    /books/:id/reviews/new(.:format)  reviews#new
edit_books_reviews GET    /books/:id/reviews/edit(.:format) reviews#edit
                       GET    /books/:id/reviews(.:format)      reviews#show
```

On top of that where are the routes for show, update and destroy actions?
I think i`m missing something fundamental, because this really sucks. Running Rails 3.2.11
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using resources instead of resource. 
Rails thinks there's only one when you use the singular form and doesn't need the ID.

For more info see the "singular resource" section of the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: That did it! I knew it had to be some stupid mistake on my part. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using `resources` over `resource` will make sure Rails accounts for many resources.

Your routes should look like this

```
resources :books do
  resources :reviews
end
```